# Spring Data Jpa getting started

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a below project structure.

[image]

And i have a main spring boot application class as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.portal.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"com.portal.repository"})
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private ResourceDataService resourceDataService;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public void list(){

         resourceDataService.find();
    }

}
```

And supporting classes are as below

```
@Service
public class ResourceDataService {

    private CalenderRepo resourceRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceDataService(CalenderRepo resourceRepo){
        this.resourceRepo = resourceRepo;
    }

    public void find(){
         resourceRepo.findAll();
    }


@Repository
public interface CalenderRepo extends CrudRepository<Calendar, Long> {

    Calendar findOneByCalendarMonth(String calendar_Month);
}
```

It throws a below error.

```
[main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.portal.services.ResourceDataService main.Application.resourceDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\M1023004\workspaceNew\MongoLab\Project\target\classes\com\portal\services\ResourceDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.portal.repository.CalenderRepo]: : Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.util.Calendar; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.util.Calendar
```

Can some one help me to resolve this error.

Also if you have got any good refference documentation for spring data jpa please share here.

Edit-1:

I have moved application.java to com.portal. I am getting the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.portal.services.ResourceDataService com.portal.Application.resourceDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\M1023004\workspaceNew\MongoLab\Project\target\classes\com\portal\services\ResourceDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.portal.repository.CalenderRepo]: : Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
    at com.portal.Application.main(Application.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.portal.services.ResourceDataService com.portal.Application.resourceDataService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\M1023004\workspaceNew\MongoLab\Project\target\classes\com\portal\services\ResourceDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.portal.repository.CalenderRepo]: : Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceDataService' defined in file [C:\Users\M1023004\workspaceNew\MongoLab\Project\target\classes\com\portal\services\ResourceDataService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.portal.repository.CalenderRepo]: : Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'calenderRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property calendarMonth found for type Calendar! Did you mean 'Calendar_Month','calendar_Month'?
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:95) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:73) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:206) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I suggest you move your `Application` to `com.portal` and remove all annotations but `@SpringBootApplication`. That will automatically enable all features you need, moving it to another package makes it a lot harder to get things to work.

Comment: I have tried your way.. and still no luck.. i have edited my post.

Comment: Instead of posting a snippet, post the full stack trace. The message is clear btw, you are using the wrong `Calendar` you are using `java.util.Calendar` instead of your own type -> `Not an managed type: class java.util.Calendar` fix your repo definition.

Comment: I have posted full stack trace..

Comment: Which indicates that you have methods in your repo that don't match the object model you have. Your `Calendar` class apparently doesn't have a `calendarMonth` property. Post your `Calendar`class.

Comment: @M.Deinum your comments resolved my issues.. Thanks!

Comment: Please use the java.util.calendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `CalenderRepo` you are using `java.util.Calendar` instead of `com.portal.model.Calendar`. Import the correct class.

Comment: Good answers +1 bro :)

Comment: @jackk Thanks for the encouragement :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public interface CalenderRepo extends CrudRepository<Calendar, Long>
```

You imported wrong class : class java.util.Calendar

Fixed :

```
public interface CalenderRepo extends CrudRepository<com.portal.model.Calendar, Long>
```